# Получить путь к файлу из библиотеки классов

Tags: asp.net, c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

Есть вебпроекты и библиотеки классов, как внутри библиотеки классов обращаться к файлам?
Относительные пути будут в конфигах. Но как внутри библиотек заресолвить этот путь?
И где вообще желательно хранить общие для вебпроектов ресурсы?

В общем задача такая: библиотека класса должна возвращать путь к файлу (имя берет  бд). Вопрос как организовать хранение и строить полные ссылки?

Comment: Предлагаю закрыть этот вопрос потому что (цитата) *"Впрочем, я уже и забыл, зачем я этот вопрос задавал."*

Comment: @PavelMayorov: Нууууу, а где же этика?

Comment: @VladD при чем тут этика? Решать эту проблему можно тысячей и еще одним способом. Хоть какой-то смысл в ответе появляется только если автор уточнит хоть что-нибудь относительно желаемой архитектуры. А если автор уже сам не помнит что там было...

Answer (score 2):

Ну так в БД и пишите полный путь до файла, в чем проблема?

А по вопросу - [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/778252/how-to-get-the-current-directory-on-a-class-library) есть вариант получения директории исполняемого файла.

```
string assemblyFile = (
    new System.Uri(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase)
).AbsolutePath;
```

Answer (score 0):

А чем `HttpContext.Current.Request.MapPath(...)` не устроил?..

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/44757)

Comment: @Oceinic нет, это именно ответ на вопрос.

Comment: @PavelMayorov только вот ответ, состоящий из вопроса, - это, мягко говоря, странно.

Comment: В том, что HttpContext не будет в данном контексте, в этой библиотеке вообще не будет референса на System.Web. Врочем, я уже и забыл, зачем я этот вопрос задавал.